# Is roloc abrasive available in an elongated cylinder / tube shape?

Tags: painting, rust-removal

EDIT: Since asking the question I've found "grinding cones" and "grinding plugs".

I've seen roloc discs but am wondering if this abrasive material is available in a tubular shape? I've been trying to search for them with  `roloc tube` and `roloc cylinder` without success. Maybe they're called something else?

An elongated cylinder shape would be great for situations where a disk doesn't fit (see pic for example). Roloc tubes in different cross-sectional diameters with an axial shaft so they could be used in a larger high-RPM rotary tool would be just the thing to remove rust and old paint from such a curlicue.

[image: wrought iron curlicue]

Comment: https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/tnpla/01608835

Comment: Thanks, that 2.5" diameter would fit into places that a 4" diameter disk would not, but I was thinking of something with a much smaller diameter, like a sausage or a finger.

Comment: You'd have limitless options for other abrasives in those sizes; there's tons of small-shanked stuff you could chuck in a drill or die grinder. (Or even pencil die grinders or rotary tools for really small stuff.) Various flap wheels, solid stones, hones, bobs with buffing compound, etc. But none of them would be the same abrasive material or have the same branding, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Roloc is primarily an attachment system for quick-change of abrasive pads/discs.

The (usual) abrasive material attached to those mounts is "non-woven abrasive" (*which you might know a specific example of by the trademarked brand-name Scotch-Brite®.*) It comes in many grades/grits as with most abrasive products. They are commonly color-coded, but color codes may not be consistent across different manufacturers.

Searching for "non-woven abrasive drum" (as in drum sander) or "non-woven abrasive flap-wheel" may yield results that will function as you want, but they won't click into a Roloc mount, as far as I'm aware (I've never seen one that does, anyway.)

I did happen across "Roloc Bristle Discs" when researching this answer, which might work for some applications.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology clarification.  I have some of the bristle disks on order and will try them out.